# Omission of the indefinite article to eliminate ambiguity

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

> love between husband and wife

What is the reason that there is no article (e.g. "love between a husband and a wife") in the above? Has some kind of a rule been identified grammatically when it comes to such a case? If I were to guess I think it's because the indefinite article 'a', the purpose of that, is taking a generic sample (or 'instance') from a 'class' (the class of husbands), but in the above sentence you want to refer to the class itself... the husband class and the wife class... and not an 'instance' of them, because it just is more to the point. Do you think this is a fair reasoning? Also, a thought came to me that with the use of the indefinite article, you get a generic husband and a generic wife, which, may not necessarily love each other (for they are not a specific pair of a specific husband and a specific wife who in fact love each other).

Comment: It is used a great deal in those cases where the generic is the main point of the idiomatic phrase, and especially it's used where there are either a lot of instances, or durability through time, or both (in golf - "He hits straight between tee and green", or "She divides her time equally between town and country.").

Comment: Congratulations! You've answered your own question! Don

Comment: The missing words are 'any' [husband] and 'that husband's' [wife].  Since the intention is to determine the universals, null determiners can be used.

Comment: @Cargill Your examples are very interesting. I don't know whether you noticed that they both include "and"? They seem to be "bare coordinations" (see below). These are very interesting - and no one knows very much about them :)

Comment: This question should be migrated to the linguistic site.

Comment: @Josh61 The linguistics site doesn't do language specific questions. This is the site for English linguistics.

Comment: @Araucaria - I think your good answer is more on the linguistic side rather than on the ELU side.

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks for the compliment.  Linguistics wouldn't allow this question on there, because it's about English.

Comment: @Araucaria - I see, that's why every time I try to post a question there, they  chase me away like the pleague. :))..my fault.

Comment: How does the omission "eliminate ambiguity*? Perhaps you could tweak your question title?

Comment: You could also use *love between the husband and the wife* when, in this case, referring to either a specific husband and wife or generic husband and wife.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but the three answers are better on this question, as is the question itself. I'd be happy to close vote the slightly older question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I agree totally that the best answers should be preserved wherever they first appeared, but believe that duplicates damage the site. Araucaria's answer is excellent. But do we want it posted three times?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth no, of course not. I'm not disputing closing two questions  but I rather feel this question is best left open. Close the older and the newest Q as duplicates of this one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth if you're wondering whether two identical answers should be deleted... that's a different matter. It's almost a self-plagiarism, but it's his own content, and it's original work. On the other hand, the 3 answers are copied verbatim... practically. P.S I don't think it is Max's fault either, he only asked a good question, since my last visit I see the question has earned a DV.

Answer (score 16):

### **Bare Coordination**

This phenomenon is one that is not at all well understood, and also one which is currently the subject of much academic research. It is an example of Bare Coordination. This is when coordinated noun phrases (NPs) which we would otherwise expect to take  a determiner of some description appear "bare" with no determiner or article at all. By coordinated, we mean that they appear in phrases using the coordinators *and*, *or*, *but* and so forth (some people call coordinators *coordinating conjunctions*). The reason that they seem to be able to appear like this is because they are in such coordinations.

Here are some more examples:

- A black cat and a brown dog were fighting in the street. Cat and dog were equally filthy.
- Are you man or mouse?
- I had pen and paper ready to make notes.
- Mother and child were said to be recovering well.
- He appeared to be millionaire and homeless vagabond at the same time.
- Nothing is so sacred as love between husband and wife.

### **Bare Coordination versus Bare Role NPs**

Notice that these aren't *bare role* NP's which specify a unique role. Bare role NPs can occur freely as Predicative Complements without a determiner. The nouns in these coordinations cannot appear bare when not in a coordination:

**Bare role NP**

- He was Managing Director at Boots.
- Who's going to be Best Man?
- We elected her treasurer.

**Nouns from the Bare Coordinations**

- *He was millionaire. (ungrammatical)
- *He used to be cat. (ungrammatical)
- *Are you mouse? (ungrammatical)
- *She was wife. (ungrammatical)

Notice as well that bare role NP's can only function as Predicative Complements. However, bare co-ordinations can appear freely in Subject or Object function:

**Bare Coordination**:

- Father and son came to see me. (Subject)
- We punished licensee and client together for the misdemeanour. (Direct Object)

**Bare Role NP**

- *Chief executive was an arse. (Subject, ungrammatical)
- *I punched Managing Director. (Object, ungrammatical)

**Definiteness**

Notice as well from the first group of examples, that it makes no difference whether the noun phrases are semantically definite or indefinite. In *man or mouse* both *man* and *mouse* are generic and don't refer to *a* or *the* man, or *the* mouse. In contrast, in *Both husband and wife are recovering well*, the husband and the wife are very specific, definite people. The fact that a noun phrase is in a bare coordination construction doesn't seem to depend on whether they are semantically definite or indefinite. Nobody knows why these bare noun phrases can occur in these coordinations. There is so much that we still don't know about language. Intriguing, isn't it!

---

**Further reading**

<sup>Here's a couple of articles on bare coordination:</sup>

<sup>- [Heycock and Zamparelli: Coordinated Bare Deﬁnites](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~heycock/coordination/bare-nouns-coord10.pdf)</sup>

<sup>- [Bare_coordination_the_semantic_shift](http://www.hum.uu.nl/medewerkers/b.s.w.lebruyn/coordination.pdf)</sup>

---

**Many thanks to FumbleFingers for the helpful comment**

Comment: I wasn't familiar with *bare role NPs* before reading this, but it seems to me your *I was nursemaid, mistress and mother to those children* is exactly the same as *He was Mayor of London and Keeper of the Records* (i.e. - they's *both* "bare role NP" usages).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're completely right. Thanks for that. I was duped because of the coordination there. All the tests would show that they are indeed bare role NP's that just happen to be in a coordination. For example, you could use one of them on its own "I was mother to those children". I've removed that example. Cheers :)

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question asked by the OP. One can say *Are you mouse or man?* or *Are you a mouse or a man?* The question is why one or the other, not how the first.

Comment: @GoDucks The answer my friend is that nobody knows, which is what I say in my post, as well as giving some further info on what it is we're looking at. And to some extent it does in fact answer the question, because it is being in a coordination that licences the noun phrases being bare.

Comment: "Notice as well that bare role NP's can only function as Predicative Complements". Except when they stand in apposition: "Chief Executive, John Smith, was an arse." Is apposition a clandestine predicate?

Comment: @TimR I often think that. A type of predicative adjunct, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the main reason why there is no article in the expression "husband and wife" is because it is an idiomatic one which represents an emblematic duality that has been mentioned  for centuries.  Other examples are : "cat and dog" or "body and soul"  for instance:

From the OED:

***Husband***:

> - A man joined to a woman by marriage. *Correlative of wife.*
>
>   - ***1765*** Blackstone Comm. I. xv. (1809) 442 By marriage, the husband and wife are one person in law.

From Etymonline:

> - Old English husbonda "male head of a household, master of a house, householder," probably from Old Norse husbondi "master of the house," literally "house-dweller." ***Beginning late 13c. it replaced Old English wer as "married man (in relation to his wife)" and became the companion word of wife,***  a sad loss for English poetry.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=husband%20and%20wife%2Cany%20husband%20and%20any%20wife%2Ca%20husband%20and%20a%20wife%2Chusbands%20and%20wives%2C%20a%20husband%20and%20wife%20&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chusband%20and%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cany%20husband%20and%20any%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20husband%20and%20a%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chusbands%20and%20wives%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20husband%20and%20wife%3B%2Cc0)***: *husband and wife, any husband and any wife, a husband and a wife, husbands and wives, a husband and wife*.

Note also the adjectival usage of "***husband-wife":***

> - pertaining to or involving a husband and his wife.
>
>   - ***1956*** J. M. Mogey Family & Neighbourhood 61 ‘My wife trusts me’ indicates excellent husband–wife adjustment.
>   - ***1959*** Encounter July 73/1 [This book] is by a husband–wife duet of French journalists.

Comment: I am not sure, checking "husband and wife" examples they appear to be consistent with the expression.

Comment: I think the Ngram in my answer is reliable in showing the more common expression of "husband and wife" compared to other combinations. If you check usage examples they appear to be consistent with the expressions quoted.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "I now pronounce you," of course!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - can you please delete your comments on Ngram, I don't thnk they are relevant in this case.

Comment: @Mari-LouA . if you use an article you create e distorsion in the results.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -            I really don't get your point. we are discussing "husband and wife" like "cat and dog" etc. any article you may use before is irrelevant. All other examples in the chart are different: a husnabd and a wife, any husband and any wife etc... The point is that the expression ***husband and wife*** is the typical, idiomatic one.

Comment: On the contrary my point is relevant, because the word preceding "husband and wife" is omitted in the Ngram search, it will therefore count all the instances where the definite and indefinite article are used. I'm not sure what is the aim of the Ngram. Is it to prove that the expression is used without any article?  Is the Ngram proving the expression exists without articles? But no one is disputing that.

Comment: The 'bare coordination' answer explains well this issue technically.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the article is missing is that we speak about a relationship. Love is the one that is described and husband and wife is explaining the type of love

- Love between mother and child
- Love between man and God
- Love between brother and sister

brother, sister, mother, child, man, God are in strict relationship, they *coexist*. You can find a husband and wife is some context as some sort of an attempt to stress this coexistence, *a* in such examples is related to both, to the pair.

In that sense *between husband and wife* is creating a background story where you place love. It is a canvas. This is not necessarily a generic usage, because it is irrelevant what usage it is applied to in one particular sentence. You can speak about specific two people and still omit the article since you speak about love that is beyond these two particular people, as a universal subject they two may or may not join, may or may not share.

In that sense, it is a form of abstract usage, which is not completely abstract since it may be applicable to the couple you have in mind, and thus for you can omit the article. Not only that you can, you feel that it is right to do so.