# Omitting articles in nouns - prepositions; after; to; before; from

Tags: prepositions, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, prepositional-phrases

Why is the indefinite article omitted here?
[image]

Could it be the definite article, but omitted? Like in the following case in an instruction:

> Grasp drumstick. Place knife between thigh and body; cut through skin
>   to joint. Separate thigh and drumstick at joint.

All those omittions would normally have the definite article, but this doesn't seem plausible in my case.

Why is there no article here, too?

[image]

I've noticed that this happens only with the following prepositons:

```
before; after; from; to || day after day; from person to person; from teacher to student
```

My questions are: **Why are the articles omitted in all those examples? Does it have something to do with comparisons? Is there any rule for this  usage?**

Answer (score 4):

You have presented two different kinds of instances.

In the first and third examples, the omission of the articles represents standard usage. In both cases, the nouns represent abstractions: "teacher and learner" are not specific people, but instead represent roles in a hypothetical or generalized situation.  "Question after question" represents no specific questions, but rather a generic and, one would think lengthy, series of interrogatories.

The second example is the sort of thing commonly found in printed instructions. The style is reminiscent of telegraphic, news headline applications. It may have risen from the need to economize on printed space, or the need to render the text simply for quick reference in a difficult and distracted environment.

(**Fire alarm - break glass and pull handle**)

*It is also possible that it imitates a documentation style that originated among persons with limited English proficiency engaged in the international export of widgets.*

Comment: Part of me is just itching to edit <strike> and </strike> (which I don't think work in comments) before and after ***the*** four words from the end of your final sentence! :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468), dropping the article of count nouns in the singular can happen (outside ['headlinese'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)) under only restricted circumstances. For completeness, I will reproduce the full discussion. Your first example belongs to the category [20vii] ('matched nouns'), while your second example belongs to [20vi] ('repeated nouns').

One caveat is that in your second example, what is repeated is a two-word noun phrase (NP) rather than a single noun. But what rules of syntax concern almost always are not individual words of a given lexical category (e.g. 'nouns'), but rather structures that have the same syntactical function (NPs, regardless of whether they consist of a single noun or a noun plus dependents).

In CGEL's terminology, if a 'noun group' is not preceded by a determiner, it is called a 'bare NP'. Other sources might say that it has a 'zero article'.

Note that the asterisk (' <sup>*</sup> ') in front of a group of words indicates that this group is not acceptable as a sentence or part of a sentence.

So here is CGEL, on the subject of bare NPs (pp. 409-410).

> **8.5 Restricted non-referential interpretations of bare NPs**
>
> Here we cover cases similar to those dealt with in §8.4, i.e. cases
> where only a restricted range of head nouns is found. This time,
> however, our concern is with bare NPs. We confine our attention to
> singular count nouns, which normally require a determiner.
>
> (a) Bare role NPs
>
> [19]  i  *Henry became **treasurer**.*
>         ii  *As
> **treasurer**, I strongly support this proposal.*
>         iii  *The role of
> **treasurer** will fall to Henry.*
>
> NPs such as *treasurer, deputy leader of the party,* occur as the
> predicative complements of verbs like *be, become, appoint, elect,* as
> oblique predicative governed by *as,* and as complement of the
> preposition *of* following nouns like *role, part, or position.* They
> cannot occur as subjects (<sup>*</sup>*I'm told **treasurer**
> strongly supports this proposal*) or objects (<sup>*</sup>*We
> dismissed **treasurer***): in these positions they require a
> determiner. The interpretation of bare role NPs is invariably
> definite: in [19], for example, we are concerned with the office of
> treasurer in some particular organisation. They are therefore
> invariably replaceable by their counterparts with determiner *the,* as
> in *Henry became **the treasurer,*** and so on.
>  It is important to
> note that only NPs which genuinely allow role interpretations can
> function in this manner. The verb *become,* for example, also allows
> non-role nouns such as *miser* as head of the predicative complement,
> but such nouns require determiners: *Fred became
> <sup>*</sup>miser/a miser when he lost his job.*
>
> (b) Fixed expressions or frames
>
> [20]  i  *Ed is in **hospital** / went to
> **school** / went off **stage**.*          [activities linked to
>                                                                                                                                             locations]
>          ii  *They
> are out of **place** / off **target** / on
> **call**.*                                   [indications
> of
>                                                                                                                                                   status]
>         iii  *We
> went by **bicycle** / communicate by
> **email**.*                              [transport
> and
>                                                                                                                                                   media]
>         iv  *We had
> **lunch** on the terrace.*                                                                            [meals]
>          v  *at
> **dawn**, by **daybreak**, before **sunrise***                                                        [times]
>         vi  ***arm**
> in **arm**, **back** to **back**, **day** after **day**,
> **mouthful***                      [repeated
>               *by
> **mouthful**, **side** by **side**, **mile** upon **mile***                                                nouns]
>         vii  *from
> **father** to **son**, from **beginning** to **end**, between*                        [matched
>               ***husband**
> and **wife**, **mother** and **child***                                                         nouns]
>
> The examples in [i] are illustrative of a number of restricted
> expressions connected with common activities of everyday life where no
> determiner is permitted, even when the noun involved is in other uses
> a singular count noun denoting a location which would require a
> determiner. In these cases, the noun acts as an indication of the
> associated activity, and does not have its standard denotation.
> Contrast, for example, *Ed is in bed* (resting/asleep) with
> referential *There are fleas in the bed*; or *Ed is in prison*
> (serving time) with *There was a riot in the prison*; or again *Ed is
> in church* (at a service) with *There is a new pulpit in the church*.
> The nouns which permit this use are severely restricted. We do not
> have for example <sup>*</sup>*Ed is at desk* (studying),
> <sup>*</sup>*Ed is at computer* (working), <sup>*</sup>*Ed is
> in kitchen* (cooking). Nevertheless there are a fair number of them:
> others include the underlined [here boldfaced] nouns in such
> expressions as *on **campus**,in **class**, at **college**, settle out
> of **court**, at **sea*** (as a sailor), *at **table*** (for a meal),
> *leave **town**, start **university**.*
>
> The examples in [20ii] relate to what we may call 'status': whether or
> not something is in its proper place, whether or not someone is
> available or engaged in their proper activity. These fixed expressions
> are comparable to those with non-count nouns such as *at work, at
> play.* The bare NPs in [iii] occur after the preposition *by*: compare
> the definite NPs in [i7iv]. Meals are generally expressed by bare NPs,
> except when a particular occasion is singled out: compare [20iv] with
> *We had **a nice lunch** at the Savoy.* Note also *at/by dinner*, where the meal indicates a time of day. Bare NPs are used for times of
> day following the prepositions *at, by, before, until, after,* as in
> [20v]; note, however, that *morning, daytime, evening,* and *dark*
> take *in* + *the* instead of *at*: *in the / <sup>*</sup>at
> morning*. The examples in [vi-vii] are illustrative of anumber of
> expressions involving repetition of the same noun or contrasting
> nouns; for thecategory status of the expressions in [vi], see Ch. 7,
> §4.3. Similarly, in coordinate structures, bare NPs can optionally be
> used in repetition: *We searched endlessly for **a spring** or **a
> cave** to spend the night, but neither **spring** nor **cave** could
> be found.*

On the subject of bare coordination, see also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300990/155553).

Comment: Yes, CGEL's treatment is good. The authors don't, however, distinguish the zero and null articles which [Master](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0) proposes ('We had Ø₁/a chicken for tea,' Ø₁ the zero, least definite, article **v**  'Thanks for the/Ø₂ lunch,' Ø₂ the null, most definite, article).

Answer (score 0):

All indefinite noun phrases begin with an indefinite determiner: a[n], one, two, some, many, ...  All other noun phrases are definite.  The definite article 'the' is required to distinguish mass nouns ('the water is good' vs 'water is good'), groups ('the two cats ate' vs 'two cats ate'), and it helps to separate individuals from concepts ('the cat is bad' vs '"cat" is a word').  In cases where definiteness is clear (from lack of a determiner on a count noun), 'the' can be omitted.  It shouldn't be done too often, but it is common when space is limited.  Note that proper nouns are typically definite in use, so we omit 'the' before names.

Comment: This answer is very careless. Basically every statement is confusing or misleading (at best). Let's start with the very first sentence. As it stands, it is just wrong, since plural indefinite NPs don't require a determiner. (Arguably, non-count nouns can also be indefinite without requiring a determiner, e.g. *I poured **water** into the glass,* when the intended meaning is *I poured some water into the glass.*) Next, what do you mean by "distinguish mass nouns" and "groups"? Your examples just illustrate that *water* and *two cats* may or may not be definite.

Comment: And as far as "cat," the principal way we know you are talking about the word itself is the quotation marks, not the absence of the determiner. And anyway "cat" does allow the definite article (e.g., *The "cat" in the sentence "My cat is cute" is a noun*), and maybe even the indefinite one (e.g., *You need a "cat" to make "My is a good mouser" into a proper sentence*).

Comment: But most importantly, it is absolutely not true that we can, under normal circumstances, arbitrarily omit the definite article (by which I take it you meant "the definite article or other determiner") "when definiteness is clear." This "optional omission" is only acceptable under special circumstances, e.g. in "headlinese." Your disclaimer that "It shouldn't be done too often, but it is common when space is limited" is not enough.

Comment: For example, no native speaker would drop the definite article at the beginning of the second sentence in this example: "I saw a cat yesterday. The cat was beautiful." And in any event, what is happening in the examples quoted in the question you are trying to answer is not a headlinese-like optional omission; instead, those examples belong to what [CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468) calls "matched nouns" (p. 409). Another example of the same phenomenon is [bare coordination](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/300990/155553).

Comment: For all these reasons, I am downvoting this answer. If you decide to fix it, please leave a comment here that starts with @linguisticturn so I will be notified of the change, and I will then upvote.