# Omission of definite article before common nouns in pairs

Tags: articles, definite-articles, proper-nouns, common-word

I am well aware that the usage of, or the omission of, the definite article "the" has been a frequently asked question, here and elsewhere. I have read up on existing questions on this matter. (But I could have missed some. So if this question has indeed been asked before, forgive me.)

My question concerns a **specific** case of article omission.
It is my understanding that the definite article can/should be omitted before certain common nouns. For [example](https://www.englishpractice.com/improve/omission-articles-cases-articles/):

> Both husband and wife received serious injuries.

Also

> In the mirror, daughter sees the future, and mother the past.

The second example is more complex, because the common noun "mother" may be used as a proper noun. AFAIK, "daughter" can't.

But come to think of it, I can't articulate the exact rules that govern this kind of omission.

The aforementioned site states the rule as follows:

> Before common nouns when they go in pairs

It doesn't really satisfy my inquisitiveness, because it's not a dictionary, and seems like a site for English learners. What kind of common nouns? Any specific rules? None of the other sites on article omission that I have found has this rule.

My question, in sum, is multi-fold.

1. Are there more authoritative sources that talk about this issue?
2. Are there more specific and detailed rules? Does the pair have to exhibit symmetry in their positions and/or functions in the sentence?
3. What is it called in linguistics, if it has a name?
4. In sentences where this rule applies, can we not omit, namely keep, the definite article? Basically, in these cases, is it "the article **can** be omitted" or "the article **should** be omitted"? (I am leaning towards "can be omitted".) Also would a sentence that keeps the articles read verbose? And what kind of nuances would people say are caused by keeping the articles? E.g. **"Both the husband and the wife received serious injuries"** v.s. **"Both husband and wife received serious injuries."**
5. This might be another can of worms, but why can't "daughter" and "son" be proper nouns, as "Mom", "Father", or can they?

Comment: Yes, daughter and son and uncle and aunt and gramps and grandma, etc. can all be used as names (proper nouns), usually if talking directly to such a person: 'Go to your room, Son' but I am not sure if 'Today Brother has no homework' is quite as kosher.

Comment: How about: The fire destroyed both house and vineyard, both weed and flower.

Comment: These seem to be cases of the null article (rather than the zero article) usage. For some reason, this is covered only on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/l-am-a-young-king-but-l-am-king-why-no-article-in-front-of-the-second-king/104200#104200).

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["With pen and paper" <-- Why don't we need an article here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409338/with-pen-and-paper-why-dont-we-need-an-article-here). @Araucaria has posted a fine article dealing with _bare coordination_ in at least three places on ELU.

Comment: @Edwin I knew there were plenty of possible duplicates but I left it to another to be able to identify and locate them. Thanks